# Check if file was modified OUTSIDE the application

Tags: c++, file, inotify

I have an application which uses `inotify` and `std::thread` to check if file is modified outside the application. The problem is that when the file is modified inside the application, `inotify` works and it is considered as updated outside. My question is, how can I check if file is modified only outside the application. Almost every text editor works that way (when file is modified outside, it asks to reload. But when you modify a text inside, it does not ask anything like that). How are those applications designed?

Comment: It is operating system specific. You mention `inotify` so probably are targetting Linux

Answer (score 1):

I don't KNOW how the editors do this, but I expect that when the application writes to the file itself, it "knows" that it did the writing, so either turns of the notifications whilst doing this, or just says "Sure, I know I wrote to the file, so I'll just ignore it".

Comment: I don't get how to tell "Sure, I know I wrote to the file, so I'll just ignore it" to a `thread`

Comment: Well, that will of course be something you'll have to figure out. Perhaps a global variable [or a non-global variable stored somewhere that the thread can get to, e.g in the thread-context] with the "timestamp of when I last wrote to the file" might do? Don't forget to use some sort of protection so you don't get a data-race when checking the variable shared between the writer thread and the "checker thread".